# PayPalRESTException with response as CREDIT_CARD_REFUSED. How to get the cause of this refusal

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I was trying to make a transaction through PayPal REST API using a saved credit card in live environment.
I have got a PayPalRESTException with response as CREDIT_CARD_REFUSED.

Here is the error message:

```
Error code : 400 with response : {"name":"CREDIT_CARD_REFUSED","message":"Credit card was refused","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#CREDIT_CARD_REFUSED","debug_id":"<some number>"}
```

Now I want to know why the card is refused and how to get any info. from this debug_id.

Is there any way to get all these failed transaction details in PayPal merchant account?

Note: The card was previously authorized and saved in paypal

Answer (score 0):

Merchants aren't usually told the reason for a CC refusal. It's none of their business after all. It's between the CC provider and the cardholder.

Comment: Okay got it, I am clear on my first question. Any light on other two?

Comment: Your other two questions assume that the merchant knows the reason. If PayPal doesn't know the reason, they can't tell you, and there are no further details to be obtained.

Comment: Okay, forget about the reason of transaction failure; Paypal is providing a debug id in exception message. How can I use it?

Comment: And in our PayPal merchant account, there is no info about this transaction failure. Is there anything I need to change in merchant account to get at least the number of payment failures per day.